# PLpgSQL (or ANSI SQL?) Conditional calculation on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want to write a stored procedure that performs a conditional calculation on a column. Ideally the implementation of the SP will be db agnostic - if possible. If not the underlying db is PostgreSQL (v8.4), so that takes precedence.

The underlying tables being queried looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE treatment_def (  id         PRIMARY SERIAL KEY,
                    name       VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
                 );

CREATE TABLE foo_group_def (  id         PRIMARY SERIAL KEY,
                    name       VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
                 );

CREATE TABLE foo (  id         PRIMARY SERIAL KEY,
                    name       VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
                    trtmt_id   INT REFERENCES treatment_def(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
                    foo_grp_id INT REFERENCES foo_group_def(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
                    is_male    BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                    cost       REAL NOT NULL
             );
```

I want to write a SP that returns the following 'table' result set:

> **treatment_name, foo_group_name, averaged_cost**

where averaged cost is calcluated differently, **depending on whether the row field *is_male* flag is set to true or false**.

For the purpose of this question, lets assume that if the is_male flag is set to true, then the averaged cost is calculated as the **SUM** of the cost values for the grouping, and if the is_male flag is set to false, then the cost value is calculated as the **AVERAGE** of the cost values for the grouping.

(Obviously) the data is being grouped by trmt_id, foo_grp_id (and is_male?).

I have a rough idea about how to to write the SQL if there was no conditional test on the is_male flag. However, I could do with some help in writing the SP as defined above.

Here is my first attempt:

```
CREATE TYPE FOO_RESULT AS (treatment_name VARCHAR(16), foo_group_name VARCHAR(64), averaged_cost DOUBLE);      

// Outline plpgsql (Pseudo code)

CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS SETOF FOO_RESULT AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT t.name treatment_name, g.name group_name, averaged_cost  FROM foo f 
                     INNER JOIN treatment_def t ON t.id = f.trtmt_id
                     INNER JOIN foo_group_def g ON g.id = f.foo_grp_id
                GROUP BY f.trtmt_id, f.foo_grp_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would appreciate some help on how to write this SP correctly to implement the conditional calculation in the column results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc()
 RETURNS TABLE (
  treatment_name varchar(16)
, foo_group_name varchar(16)
, averaged_cost double precision)
AS
$BODY$

    SELECT t.name          -- AS treatment_name
         , g.name          -- AS group_name
         , CASE WHEN f.is_male THEN sum(f.cost)
                               ELSE avg(f.cost) END -- AS averaged_cost  
    FROM   foo f 
    JOIN   treatment_def t ON t.id = f.trtmt_id
    JOIN   foo_group_def g ON g.id = f.foo_grp_id
    GROUP  BY 1, 2, f.is_male;

$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### Major points

- I used an `sql` function, not `plpgsql`. You can use either, I just did it to shorten the code. `plpgsql` might be slightly faster, because the query plan is cached.
- I skipped the custom composite type. You can do that simpler with [`RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).
- I would generally advise to use the [data type `text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) instead of `varchar(n)`. Makes your life easier.
- Be careful not to use names of the RETURN parameter without table-qualifying (`tbl.col`) in the function body, or you will create naming conflicts. That is why I commented the aliases.
- I adjusted the `GROUP BY` clause. The original didn't work. (Neither does the one in @Ken's answer.)

Comment: +1 for clean simple ANSI SQL that works. Once again, you saved my bacon! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT t.name treatment_name, g.name group_name, 
  CASE is_male WHEN true then SUM(cost)
   ELSE AVG(cost) END AS averaged_cost  
FROM foo f 
  INNER JOIN treatment_def t ON t.id = f.trtmt_id
  INNER JOIN foo_group_def g ON g.id = f.foo_grp_id
GROUP BY 1, 2, f.is_male;
```

I'm not familiar with `PLpgSQL`, so I'm not sure of the exact syntax for the `BOOLEAN` column, but the above should at least get you started in the right direction.